# Java - converting string to a List

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is this the right way to convert a string to a list?

```
List styles = (List)request.getParameter("styles");

    Model (BeerExpert.java)

package com.example.model;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerExpert {
    public List getBrands(String color){
        List brands = new ArrayList();
        if(color.equals("amber")){
            brands.add("Jack Amber");
            brands.add("Red Moose");
        }
        else{
            brands.add("Jail Pale Ale");
            brands.add("Gout Scott");
        }
        return brands;
    }
}
```

The next is the servlet class

```
BeerSelect.java

package com.example.web;

import com.example.model.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response)
                        throws IOException,ServletException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("Beer Selection Advice <br>");
        String c = request.getParameter("color");

        BeerExpert be = new BeerExpert();
        List result = be.getBrands(c);

        request.setAttribute("styles", result);
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("results.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Finally the jsp.

```
 results.jsp

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center">Beer Recommendations in JSP!!!</h1>
        <%
            List styles = (List)request.getParameter("styles");
            Iterator it = styles.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                out.print("<br> try " + it.hasNext());
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what is the type of `request`?

Comment: You want to convert a string into a list based on... what, exactly? Do you want a list of all the characters in the string? Do you want to split the string on specific separators? Or do you simply want to insert the string as is in a list?

Comment: Or perhaps `request.getParameter(..)` returns `Object` and in this case it is known that `styles` will produce an object of type `List`... no way to tell without more information.

Comment: Well, at first glance it seems to be the retrieval of a HTTP request parameter, usually those methods indeed return a `String` object.

Comment: I have edited my question with that code that I was working on. The code is from 'Head first servlets and jsps'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the additional servlet/JSP context you provided, it seems that the *real* mistake in your code is the use of `request.getParameter` in the JSP page: that method indeed returns a `String`, and you can't *convert* a `String` in a `List`, not with a cast, not even with any other operation allowed by the language or the data structures. You may *insert* a `String` into a `List`, using one of the methods already suggested (or *transform* a `List` into a `String` using other methods), but judging from the code that's not what you need.

In the servlet code, you set the `styles` *attribute* to the `List` containing the beer brands. So, to get that `List` back, you need to invoke `request.getAttribute` instead of `getParameter`. The `getAttribute` methods returns an `Object`, which really is a `List`, and you know that because you have set it to be as such, so in this case a cast is exactly the operation that is needed to get back the value with its original type. In code, this means

```
List styles = (List) request.getAttribute("styles");
```

in your JSP, in place of the line that got you troubles.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use getAttribute, the result is displaying the value of true and goes into infinite loop

Comment: Whoops, yes, there's another error in code. `Iterator.hasNext` checks whether there's another element to navigate in the list, but to actually get that element in the `print` call you need to invoke `Iterator.next`. Sorry I didn't see it at first glance.

Comment: @Guilio. Thanks for the answer. you have explained it very well. It works now

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(yourString);
```

Just keep in mind that you won't be able to change the contents of the list. If you need to do that, create another list from this one manually.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, what you're doing is trying to **cast** a `String` to a `List`, which is not the same.  A **cast** doesn't convert object, it merely tries to tell what *type* an object is.

What you need to do is:

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
list.add(request.getParameter("styles"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve more "styles" you can use:

```
request.getParameterValues("styles")
```

that will return an array of String, that could be used to create a List as follows:

```
List<String> styles = java.util.Arrays.asList(request.getParameterValues("styles"))
```